# Is there any way to set defaults in supertest?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, supertest

I'm using the [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) module to test my Rest API. my API sends JSON all the time. so I'm doing `.expect('Content-Type', /json/)` for all and each test! I'm repeating again and again!

this is some of my code

```
it('should list ALL permissions on /permissions GET', (done)=> {
    request(app)
        .get( permissionsURL )
        .expect(200)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res)=> {
            var permissions = res.body;
            permissions.should.be.an.instanceOf(Array);
            var permission = permissions[0];
            permission.should.be.json;
            permission.should.have.properties(['name', '_id']);
            permission.name.should.be.a.String();
            // permission.should.not.have.property('__v');

            done(err);
        });
});

it('should list a SINGLE permission on /permissions/<id> GET', (done)=> {
    request(app)
        .get( permissionsURL +savedPermissionId )
        .expect(200)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res)=> {
            var permission = res.body;
            permission.should.be.json;
            permission.should.have.properties(['name', '_id']);
            permission.name.should.be.a.String();
            // permission.should.not.have.property('__v')

            done(err);
        });
});
```

Is there any other way? somethink like the [superagent-defaults](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-defaults) module but for supertest not superagent? or is it possible to use superagent-defaults with supertest?

thank you for any help you are able to provide. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set this for all the tests. However, if you could consider having a suite of tests for each endpoint that you expect to return JSON and just have this expect call in there, then you could omit the expect for every other test.